# jQuery Validetta datepicker works only the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using jQuery Validetta form validation. What I noticed is that on the datepicker, the validation works only the second time. Tried a lot of codes here but none seemed to work. The ff are:

**Datepicker code:**

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
});
```

**Test code:**

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onClose: function () {
        $('#myForm').validetta();
    }
});

$("#datepicker").on('keyup blur', function () {
    $('#myForm').validetta();
});
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/8w8v9/2781/).
But my doubt is why do you want to initialize `validetta`  `onClose` of datepicker.It will work fine [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/8w8v9/2782/) initialize by default

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  onClose: function() {
    $('form').validetta({
      realTime: true,
      bubblePosition: 'bottom',
      realTime: true
    });
  }
});
```